# How Do I Control The Font Style After Moving Data From Excel To Word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, font-face, font-size

I have the below working code. I added the With statement but it formats all text on page.
This code takes each row from an excel table and extracts the column header (question) and the cell value (answer) just below it.

My goal is to have the question in bold and one font size and the answer below it normal font and a smaller size.
I tried wrapping the With statement around just the header code but it still stylizes the entire page

```
For Each cell In tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows:

If cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    hiddenCell = cell.Row
    
    
    For Each Header In tbl.HeaderRowRange:

    With WordDoc
    .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Size = 12
    .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Bold = True
    .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Color = wdColorBlack
    .Range(0).Style = .Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
    
        headerCol = wks.Cells.Find(Header).Column
        WordDoc.Content.InsertAfter (vbNewLine)
        WordDoc.Content.InsertAfter Range(Header.Address).Value & ": "
        WordDoc.Content.InsertAfter (vbNewLine)
        WordDoc.Content.InsertAfter (Cells(hiddenCell, headerCol).Value)
        'WordDoc.Content.InsertAfter (vbNewLine)
    End With
        
    Next
WordDoc.Sections.Add
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with you need to take defining Heading 1 out of the loop. You only need to define a style once.

You also format the document with the Heading 1 style within the loop. Again this does not need to be repeated.

What your code does not do is apply any other style to the answers.

I have redrafted your code setting both the text and the style for the last paragraph.

```
  With WordDoc
    With .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font
      .name = "Arial"
      .Size = 12
      .Bold = True
      .Color = wdColorBlack
    End With
    .Range(0).style = .Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
  End With

  For Each Cell In tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows:

    If Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then hiddenCell = Cell.Row
    
    For Each Header In tbl.HeaderRowRange:

      With WordDoc
        headerCol = wks.Cells.Find(Header).Column
        
        .Content.InsertAfter (vbNewLine)
        With .Paragraphs.Last.Range
          .Text = Range(Header.Address).Value & ": "
          .style = wdStyleHeading1
        End With
        .Content.InsertAfter (vbNewLine)
        With .Paragraphs.Last.Range
          .Text = Cells(hiddenCell, headerCol).Value
          .style = wdStyleNormal
        End With
      End With
        
    Next Header
    WordDoc.Sections.add
  Next Cell
```